# Наиболее точный вариант таймера для MFC C++

Tags: c++, время, таймер, mfc

Уважаемые коллеги!
В моем приложении MFC должна выводится некоторая строка в `list control` через некоторый промежуток времени от 50 до 1000 миллисекунд.

Я попробовал два решения. Первое решение - через таймер. Функции `SetTimer` и `KillTimer`. Не понравилось, потому что, до 15 миллисекунд погрешность, при задании 100 миллисекунд в качестве интервала. Пруфпик порнографии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Второе решение более точное - через функцию:

```
Sleep(100); //100 миллисекунд.
```

Вполне нормальная погрешность - не более 2 миллисекунд. Не нравится, что во время выполнения этой функции, программа виснет и не хочет выполнять другие действия. Пруфпик,  что погрешности практически нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого, в первом варианте большая погрешность, во втором варианте погрешности нет, но виснет до окончания измерений.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли решение для **MFC**, такое что погрешность была не более 4-5 миллисекунд, при задании интервала между измерениями от 50 до 1000 миллисекунд? И нужно, чтобы ничего не висло. И желательно, чтобы без утечек памяти.

Comment: Попробуйте CreateWaitableTimer, как [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630132/windows-waitabletimers-in-c)